# Altering the size of a single slide without interfering with default slide size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am producing a survey Slide_1 of my slides needs to be considerably longer than the other slides. How do I edit the slide size without interfering with the default size of the others.?

I have tried creating another body height variable specifically for slide_1 and editing the height from 800 to 2500 however this didn't work. The size of the slide did not change.

```
  var bodywidthslide = $(document).width();
  if  (bodywidthslide <2500) bodywidthslide = 2500;
  var bodyWidth = $(document).width();
  var bodyHeight = $(document).height() - 20;
  if (bodyWidth < 800) bodyWidth = 800;
  if (bodyHeight < 750) bodyHeight = 750;
  var center = bodyWidth / 2;
  var middle = bodyHeight / 200;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", bodyWidth)
    .attr("height", bodyHeight)
    .on("contextmenu", function() {d3.event.preventDefault()});

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([bodyWidth, bodyHeight])
    .nodes([{x:bodyWidth / 2,
              y:bodyHeight / 2.2,
              fixed: true,

var slide_1 = d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("id", "slide1");
  slide_1.append("rect")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", bodywidthslide)
    .attr("height", bodyHeight);
```

So I want slide_1 to have a larger slide height, so I can fit on more information for participants to scroll and read. At the moment it cuts off that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the CSS of your Parent div.

```
.style("overflow", "scroll")
```

Comment: Sorry I'm sort of a novice at code. What do you mean? Where should I put the .attr?

Comment: Sorry, I might be a bit rusty:)  document.getElementById(yourParentDivID).style.overflow = "scroll". Also check out MDN for overflow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow